# How do I change the page number size after a certain page number?

Tags: header-footer, fontsize

I use LaTeX to typeset my notes. At the beginning of each document, I have the following code which makes a duck at the bottom of the page holding a sign with the page number on it:

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyfoot[C]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
\shuffleducks
\duck[water=cyan!50!blue, \randomhead, signpost = {\bf \color{black} \thepage}, signback =white]
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

This works fine for shorter docouments. However, when the document goes 100 pages or over, the page number is now too big to fit in the sign and overflows, hence does not look very good. It seems like I need to lower the size of the font of the page number after I reach page 100, but I haven't figured out how to do this. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyfoot[C]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,%transform shape %also possible to get smaller font
   ]
\shuffleducks
\duck[water=cyan!50!blue, \randomhead, signpost = {\bfseries \color{black}\ifnum\value{page}>99 \scriptsize\fi \thepage}, signback =white]
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{99}
abc \newpage abc \newpage abc
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: (I added the nice output, hope that's ok.)

Answer (score 4):

You can just use Ti*k*Z to scale the node contents as required. This allows you to use pgf math to determine the scale factor, which is freely adjustable.

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyfoot[C]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,%transform shape %also possible to get smaller font
   ]
\shuffleducks
\duck[water=cyan!50!blue,\randomhead,
/tikz/nodes={scale/.evaluated={\value{page}>99?0.6:0.8},font=\bfseries}, 
signpost = {\color{black}\thepage}, signback =white]
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{99}
abc \newpage abc \newpage abc
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]